# Finding first letter in NSString and counting backwards

Tags: ios, parsing, nsstring, nsscanner

I'm new to IOS, and was looking for some guidance.

I have a long NSString that I'm parsing out.  The beginning may have a few characters of garbage (can be any non-letter character)  then 11 digits or spaces, then a single letter (A-Z).  I need to get the location of the letter, and get the substring that is 11 characters behind the letter to 1 character behind the letter.

Can anyone give me some guidance on how to do that?

Example: `'!!2553072      C'`

and I want : `'53072      '`

Comment: I'm assuming you really do mean 11 characters, and your example is just short - the string you say you want is only 6 characters long.

Comment: yeah sorry they cut off multiple white spaces when posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a more elegant way to do this involving regular expressions or some Objective-C wizardry, but here's a straightforward solution (personally tested).

```
-(NSString *)getStringContent:(NSString *)input
{
    NSString *substr = nil;
    NSRange singleLetter = [input rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet]];
    if(singleLetter.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSInteger startIndex = singleLetter.location - 11;
        NSRange substringRange = NSMakeRange(start, 11);
        substr = [tester substringWithRange:substringRange];
    }

    return substr;
}
```

Comment: These are all super helpful, but I used this method.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this with the regex pattern: `(.{11})\b[A-Z]\b`

The `(.{11})` will grab any 11 characters and the `\b[A-Z]\b` will look for a single character on a word boundary, meaning it will be surrounded by spaces or at the end of the string. If characters can follow the `C` in your example then remove the last `\b`. This can be accomplished in Objective-C like so:

```
NSError *error;
NSString *example = @"!!2553072      C";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
                              regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(.{11})\\b[A-Z]\\b"
                              options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                              error:&error];

if(!regex)
{
    //handle error
}

NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:example
                                                options:0
                                                  range:NSMakeRange(0, [example length])];
if(match)
{
    NSLog(@"match: %@", [example substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NSCharacterSet](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)s to split up the string, then take the first remaining component (consisting of your garbage and digits) and get a substring of that. For example (not compiled, not tested):

```
- (NSString *)parseString:(NSString *)myString {
    NSCharacterSet *letters = [NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet];
    NSArray *components = [myString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:letters];
    assert(components.count > 0);
    NSString *prefix = components[0]; // assuming relatively new Xcode
    return [prefix substringFromIndex:(prefix.length - 11)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//to get rid of all non-Digits in a NSString
NSString *customerphone = CustomerPhone.text;
int phonelength = [customerphone length];
NSRange customersearchRange = NSMakeRange(0, phonelength);
for (int i =0; i < phonelength;i++)
{
    const unichar c = [customerphone characterAtIndex:i];
    NSString* onechar = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&c length:1];
    if(!isdigit(c))
    {
        customerphone = [customerphone stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:onechar withString:@"*" options:0 range:customersearchRange];
    }
}
NSString *PhoneAllNumbers = [customerphone stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"*" withString:@"" options:0 range:customersearchRange];
```